# Problem with updating nuget packages in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, rider

I really need your help with JetBrains Rider

Every other developer on our project has Visual Studio 2019, except for me. I prefer JetBrains Rider.
Precisely in the solution I am talking about, .NET Framework 4.7.2 is used.

The problem comes when there is a need to update the nuget packages.
All guys who do it on Visual Studio 2019 receive the following string in the .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Common.Communication, Version=8.0.20170.2, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Common.Communication.8.0.20170.2\lib\net452\Common.Communication.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

if I do the same update on Rider I get the following string:

```
<Reference Include="Common.Communication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Common.Communication.8.0.20170.2\lib\net45\Common.Communication.dll</HintPath>
 <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

what is the reason for such different update result?
And how can I fix this to make consistent on any IDE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rider is a paid product.  Have you asked their support this question?  Many times companies don't even know that they have an issue unless people contact support.  Also products like Rider (very cool product) will ALWAYS be playing catch-up to visual studio.  Get used to it not working 100%

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for the hint, I will post the same question at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: Having the same issue. There is an issue logged on youtrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-22324 but (as usual) JetBrains are just ignoring it. The issue is even flagged as "fixed", even though nobody from JetBrains has even acknowledged it!